# View fees in PayPal sandbox account

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have just downloaded the `AdaptivePaymentsSample` SDK and did some test calls for  Parallel Payments using my sandbox test accounts. Everything looks good but I added this line of code in order to simulate fees for each receiver:

`request.feesPayer = "EACHRECEIVER";`

Where can I view that fees has been implemented for the transaction in my sandbox account?

Answer (score 0):

If you login www.paypal.com, in transaction history page, you will get the transaction list, in each record, there is a fee column, as this image:[image]